# Scrapy: What's the correct way to use start_requests()?

Tags: python, scrapy

This is how my spider is set up

```
class CustomSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'custombot'
    allowed_domains = ['www.domain.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.domain.com/some-url']
    rules = ( 
              Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'.*?something/'), callback='do_stuff', follow=True),
            )

    def start_requests(self):
        return Request('http://www.domain.com/some-other-url', callback=self.do_something_else)
```

It goes to /some-other-url but not /some-url. What is wrong here? The url specified in start_urls are the ones that need links extracted and sent through the rules filter, where as the ones in start_requests are sent directly to the item parser so it doesn't need to pass through the rules filters.

Answer (score 15):

From the [documentation for `start_requests`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests), overriding `start_requests` means that the urls defined in `start_urls` are ignored.

> This is the method called by Scrapy when the spider is opened for
>   scraping when no particular URLs are specified. If particular URLs are
>   specified, the make_requests_from_url() is used instead to create the
>   Requests.
>   [...]
>   If you want to change the Requests used to start scraping a domain, this is the method to override.

If you want to just scrape from /some-url, then remove `start_requests`. If you want to scrape from both, then add /some-url to the `start_urls` list.

Comment: If I add /some-url to start_requests then how do I make it pass through the rules in rules() to set up the right callbacks?×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes.

This is the scenario. The /some-url page contains links to other pages which needs to be extracted. The /some-other-url contains json responses so there are no links to extract and can be sent directly to the item parser.

Comment: I hope this approach is correct but I used init_request instead of start_requests and that seems to do the trick.

Comment: Possibly a bit late, but if you still need help then edit the question to post all of your spider code and a valid URL. :)